# How on earth did this question get upvoted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I was browsing questions to edit today, looking for bad grammar and fluff. Usually my search turns up no-vote or downvoted questions, but [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47805825/8718143) ([<10K](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGJbN.png)) has a whole three upvotes at the time of writing. Which strikes me as really odd. The question is borderline incomprehensible, and doesn't include any code to illustrate the user's problem.

How could this have happened? Do users genuinely like the question or is the user likely just using sock puppet accounts to upvote themselves?

Also, what's the appropriate response to such a question, should I run into a similar situation in future?

Comment: By the way Laura, if a question should be closed and isn't worth it, I would strongly suggest not editing it. Until you are => 2K rep, you need some other users to review your edit. Considering this question will likely be deleted, you can spend your time (and the reviewer's time as well) on questions that are worth more efforts :)

Comment: Thanks @Patrice, I'm still working out which questions are worth editing. I did the edit before I noticed the discrepancy with the upvotes though, otherwise I might have left it.

Comment: The dark side of hat season: some folks pull their hats down over their eyes and can't see what they're voting on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Also, what's the appropriate response to such a question, should I run into a similar situation in future?

Quietly flag it for moderator attention, explain that you believe the question is poor and that some illicit voting may have taken place.  No need to involve Meta; all *we're* gonna do is downvote it to oblivion (and/or close it).

Comment: The Meta effect is quicker than I thought. I will put your advice into practice in future.